# Who else has stopped the "Unstoppable" Juggernaut in battle?

Tags: marvel, comics, juggernaut

Contrary to his moniker, Cain Marko (The Unstoppable Juggernaut)n_has_ been literally "stopped" cold before. True, it's usually by some **INHUMANELY POWERFUL** beings, but that goes without saying. The shortlist includes Gladiator....

Onslaught....

And of course, The Hulk....

Okay, maybe *that* example was a bit questionable; try *this* one....

[image]

Are there any other in-universe examples of beings who have managed to "Stop" the Unstoppable?

Comment: This seems very broad. Do you mean in comic, on TV, in films? He's appeared thousands of times in fiction

Comment: Did Juggernaut ever  choose to oppose Captain America's mighty shield?

Comment: Well, if you're counting film, then Kitty Pryde stopped him during the Alcatraz battle in X-Men: The Last Stand.

Comment: Deadpool and Co. managed it pretty effectively.

Comment: @Valorum Note how I used examples from TV shows _and_ comics. It could be used with either, but I suppose the comics would be a bit more solid.